# Samba4 AD DC setup and working, but won't connect with Windows 7 or 10

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, samba4, ubuntu-18.04

I've gotten a Samba 4 AD DC setup running on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I used this tutorial to make it work:

https://www.tecmint.com/install-samba4-active-directory-ubuntu/

The problem is I can't get my Windows 7 or 10 clients to connect to the domain.

Here is my `krb5.conf` file:

```
[logging]
default = FILE:/var/log/krb-def.log
kdc = FILE:/var/log/kdc.log
admin_server = FILE:/var/log/lrb-adm.log

[libdefaults]
default_realm = MVPOSERVER.LAN

[realms]
MVPOSERVER.LAN = {
   default_domain = mvposerver.lan
   kdc = adc1.mvposerver.lan:88
}
```

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.9.50    mvposerver
192.168.9.50    mvposerver.lan adc1 _kerberos._udp _ldap._tcp _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs
192.168.9.50    adc1.mvposerver.lan
192.168.9.50    _kerberos._udp.mvposerver.lan
192.168.9.50    _ldap._tcp.mvposerver.lan
192.168.9.50    _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mvposerver.lan
```

My `netplan` IP config is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      dhcp4: no
      dhcp6: no
      addresses: [192.168.9.50/24]
      gateway4:  192.168.9.250
      nameservers:
              search: [mvposerver.lan]
              addresses: [127.0.0.1, 192.168.9.250]
```

Samba config:

[image]

Host returns the IP:

```
# host -t A mvposerver.lan
mvposerver.lan has address 192.168.9.50
```

Hostname of the server is `adc1`. `klist` returns the created Admin, so it's connecting:

```
# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: administrator@MVPOSERVER.LAN

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
06/18/2019 15:34:17  06/19/2019 01:34:17  krbtgt/MVPOSERVER.LAN@MVPOSERVER.LAN
    renew until 06/19/2019 15:34:14
```

And `samba-tool` works for user listing:

```
# samba-tool user list
Administrator
krbtgt
Guest
```

Yet connecting Windows 7 Pro won't return ping on the hostname, nor will it connect to the controller. If I ping the hostname `mvposerver.lan`, which does return the IP on the server itself, it won't resolve it:

[image]
[image]
[image]

If I ping the Samba NETBIOS name it does return an IP:

[image]

Also, I know Kerberos is working, because in Windows 7 if I make my domain `mvposerver` instead of `mvposerver.lan` it does ask me to connect using credentials, but then errors out after:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I also can't ping `google.com` or any other domain name from the Windows client once on DNS through the DC. I can ping `google.com` from the DC server in terminal just fine, I can also ping `8.8.8.8` from the client, just not domain resolve.

**EDIT**

I installed Bind9, setup DNS records, now the server won't ping it's own hostname, nor does the client still. But client does have internet now.

DNS Setup:

[image]

**EDIT2**

I have updated my DNS records and got DNS working, now the client has internet and detects the hostnames correctly:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

So now the client finds the DC by hostname just fine, and it even finds the hostname and IP, but it can't find the DC software running, even though Samba says it's there.

Comment: Can you make sure 389 is open?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a DNS problem. I'm assuming the hosts file you showed is on the server? That's for the server's DNS client component, not for the server's DNS Server component. That's also not going to help other clients resolve DNS for AD.

Do you have a DNS server hosting the DNS zone for AD? If not, you need one and you need to configure the clients that you want to join to the domain to use it.

Comment: Thanks. As I put above the client computer I changed it's primary DNS server to the Host: https://i.stack.imgur.com/50lyE.png

Comment: Right. So the server is running DNS and has a DNS zone for AD and has all of the correct A and SRV records?

Comment: No, server is not running NameD or anything like that, the only thing on the server running DNS is the `/etc/hosts` file that points those domains to it's IP. Does the server need NameD running then as well?

Comment: I installed Bind9, setup DNS records, now the server doesn't ping itself from the hostname, nor does the client still. But client does have internet now.

Comment: AD requires a DNS server to host the AD DNS zones and the accompanying A, SRV, etc. records. You'll need to make sure that Bind is setup correctly and that you have a DNS zone and DNS records for AD. Maybe this will help - https://www.serverlab.ca/tutorials/linux/network-services/using-linux-bind-dns-servers-for-active-directory-domains/

Comment: DNS records are setup correctly now, the client can now find the IP address and host, but now says it cannot find the domain controller running. Please see updated info above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add this to SAMBA configuration:

Under [Global] add:

min protocol = SMB2

Then restart it.

( SMB1 is deprecated )

Comment: Nope, same deal.